# Dom error while executing code in selenium

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, automation

while executing my code in selenium I'm getting Dom error:

```
select. subdistrict=new.select(present subdistrict)
wait.until(expected condition.visibility of (present subdistrict));
subdistrict.select by index(1);
```

By using thread sleep I'm not getting this error.

Comment: This is not valid Java code. Please post valid code, what the actual error message is, and the relevant HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.